# wordpress primary and secondary navigation

Tags: wordpress

The below is my landing page "Products". it will display 2 columns, in the left is the secondary navigation and the right is the content. i want that if someone click in the primary navigation "Products". In second navigation the first item will in bold and will display the content.

```
<?php
/*
  Template Name: Product Navigation Page
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

  <div class="container page-border-top">

  <div id="product-navigation" class="col-md-3" style="border: 1px solid green;">

     <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

      <?php

        $args2 = array(
          'menu'        => 'product-menu',
          'menu_class'  => 'nav navbar-nav',
          'theme_location' => 'product-menu',
          'container'   => 'false'
        );
        wp_nav_menu( $args2 );

      ?>

    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-9" style="border: 1px solid red;">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

          <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
  </div>

  </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: The page behind the link "Products" from the primary nav, is that the page for the first item?

Comment: Yes, the landing page. I will be using "Products" as a landing page and the secondary navigation is attached to it. I also set all the items in secondary navigation as a parent of "Products" so it will use the template. thanks

Comment: In this case the second nav should provide the usual css class names and the first item should have the class `current-menu-item`. So you can style this class in bold.

Comment: the first sir the client will click the "Products" and it should open the first item. the problem is when the "Products" is click. the "Products" has the current-menu-item not the first item at first because clients will click first to the "Products". there im having trouble.

Comment: What post type are the products? page? If so, are the products child pages of "Product"?

Answer (score 0):

If your landing page "Products" has no parent, and if all products child pages of "Products", then you can use this template file for the landing page and for all child pages (products):

```
<?php
/*
  Template Name: Product Navigation Page
*/

$redirect = false;
$parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post->ID );

if ( ! $parent_id ) {
    $redirect = true;
    $parent_id = $post->ID;
}

// get all child's
$all_wp_pages = $wp_query->query(array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));

$childs = get_page_children( $parent_id, $all_wp_pages );

if ( $redirect ) {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( $childs[0]->ID ) );
    exit;
}

$current_page_id = $post->ID;

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

  <div class="container page-border-top">

  <div id="product-navigation" class="col-md-3" style="border: 1px solid green;">

     <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

      <ul class="menu">
        <?php foreach ( $childs as $child ): ?>
          <li class="<?php if ( $current_page_id == $child->ID ): ?>current-menu-item<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink( $child->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $child->post_name; ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>

    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-9" style="border: 1px solid red;">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

          <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
  </div>

  </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

You dont't have to create a menu for the products, it just list all child pages, and you can sort the products by the Order field (Page Attributes).

**Step by Step:**

1. Create a page "Products" and select the template file above for it (Product Navigation Page)
2. Create some product pages as childs of "Products" and select also the template file above for it (Product Navigation Page).

The template file will automaticly create the desired secondary navigation on the left side. The current product has a css class `current-menu-item`, so you can style it in bold.

**This part generates the second nav:**

```
<ul class="menu">
  <?php foreach ( $childs as $child ): ?>
    <li class="<?php if ( $current_page_id == $child->ID ): ?>current-menu-item<?php endif; ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink( $child->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $child->post_name; ?></a></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: You mean secondary navigation is not necessary?

And for primary navigation "Products" (Parent) i will set order of child so that it will display below the Parent? But how can I display it in the left side of the page?

Comment: I did this but child pages did not display. Is there a code i need to insert in my Product Navigation Page(Template Page) to make it appear?

Comment: Do you use exactly the whole code of my answer? I've tested it, and it works.